# Как отправить пользователю его ранее отправленные сообщения на Aiogram telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

await bot.send_photo – позволяет отправить пользователю фотографию и его ранее введенные сообщения.
Мне нужно сделать тоже самое только без фотографии, чем я могу воспользоваться?
К примеру, пользователь вводит имя(отправляет),затем число(отправляет).Бот присылает сообщение, в котором есть имя и число,отправленные ранее пользователем.

Comment: Используйте FSM https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: в 114 строчке есть md и bold,что это такое

Comment: Расскажите поподробнее, насколько старые сообщения? Вы их собираетесь хранить, или просто отвечать на слова пользователя его предыдущим сообщением?

Comment: @user536675 Будьте внимательнее md это import aiogram.utils.markdown as md